# display div inline unless outer div already moved

Tags: html, css, resize, inline

Ok it's kind of hard to describe what I mean so I couldn't really search for it but I will try to explain it in a good way (can't upload pictures)

I have  a div-container A with 3 divs inside (A1, A2, A3) and a div-container B with three divs inside as well (B1, B2, B3)
These div-containers are in a an area that is resizable by the user and at the moment they are all displayed in a line when there is enough space but when the user makes the area smaller, B3 gets pushed into the second line first, then B2 etc.

What I want now is that when the user makes the area smaller, FIRST all elements of B get pushed to the second line (because they belong together) and then if the area shrinks further, B3 and A3 also get pushed down until you have all elements lined up below each other

I hope this isn't too confusing and maybe someone can tell me if and how this is possible to accomplish

What it looks like at the moment: before

A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3

after resizing a little

A1 A2 A3 B1 B2

B3

after resizing a lot

A1

A2

A3

B1

... (this should be the same outcome after making the div very thin) but what I want in the second case after resizing a little is:)

A1A2A3

B1B2B3

and then

A1A2

A3

B1B2

B3

So kind of make the inline command execute first on the outer div and only after that on the inside divs - hope this is understandable

Comment: Just create a JSFiddle with your codes. Would be easy to give you a solution

Comment: for some reason the css resize command doesnt seem to work in jsfiddle, but here is the content part of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/3gL91v3x/5/
you can just resize the window to get the same effect

Comment: I couldn't quite understand why you would keep adding an amount to the amounts.  What will the dark container labels contain?  Is this like a shopping cart where you say, 1 pound of copper, add 4 of them, for example?  If so, I would separate them.

Comment: it's for a Pen and Paper user interface where you play as a character who could earn or loose money throughout the game - it's story based so it doesn't get calculated automatically and you can add or remove some at any time. To the right of the container which also contains other character data is a map and you can make the map bigger thus making the left container smaller which should cause the elements to reorder nicely - What exactly would you separate?

Comment: I would give each Copper, Silver, Gold a separate 'Add Amount'. Stack them rather as Copper-Add Amount, Silver-Add Amount, Gold-Add Amount.

Comment: then I would have 3 textfields and 3 buttons instead of 1 each though that would take up a lot of extra space, I don't really like especially since it also reduces clarity ( I hope it's the right word)

Comment: I don't know how your game works strategically but you would also need a  'remove' button?

Comment: you can type in e.g. -5 if you want to remove 5 coins

Answer (score 0):

You indicated that you have a div A & div B.

Inside A there are (A1, A2, A3)->taking up 50% of screen and inside B are (B1, B2, B3) -> taking up 50% of the screen.  When screen gets smaller, the div B should skip down as a group like this:

Row1:  A (A1, A2, A3)

Row2:  B (B1, B2, B3)

Since they are in an odd number, the best distribution for a responsive website would be giving all your sub-divs 100%.  You can use @media for this.

However, for your div A & div B use 100% inside @media, as soon as the 3 sub-divs skip as
Row1: (A1, A2)

Row2: A3

Row4: (B1, B2)

Row5: B3

As for @media, if you have not used it before inside your CSS file, we can lead you in finding out how to resolve that part.

I hope I am clear on how to apply both combined.

EDIT

I added some divs to the html and CSS by including @media methods for you.

```css
.container {
 width: 870px;
}
.group_a {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 35%;
}
.group_b {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 47%;
}

.money {
  padding: 0px;
}

.value {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
  /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
  background-color: #989898;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.addMoney {
  display: inline;
}

.showMoney {
  display: inline;
  /*float:left;*/
}

/*****  @media Area where you adjust your screen size and put your values accordingly   **************/  

@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .group_a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .group_b {
    margin-top: 1em !important;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 740px) {}@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 740px) {
  .group_a {
    width: 100%;
  }
    .group_b {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1em !important;
  }
}
  @media only screen and (min-width: 740px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .group_a {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .group_b {
 margin-top: 1em;
    width: 100%;
  }
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width 769px) and (max-width: 992px) {

    .group_a {
      width: 75%;
    }
    .group_b {
 margin-top: 1em !important;
    width: 100%;
  }
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="container">
<!-- Group A -->
<div class="group_a">
  <div class='money'>
    <div class='showMoney'>
      <div class='value'>C: *amount*</div>
      <div class='value'>S: *amount*</div>
      <div class='value'>G: *amount*</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Group A -->


<!-- Group B -->
<div class="group_b">
  <div class='addMoney'>
    <input type='text' name='moneyAmount' placeholder='amount' id='moneyAmount' style='width: 55px' />
    <select name='moneyType' id='moneyType'>
      <option value='0'>Copper</option>
      <option value='1'>Silver</option>
      <option value='2'>Gold</option>
    </select>
    <a onclick='addMoney()' class='Add' style='text-decoration:none;'>Add</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End of Group B -->

</div><!-- End of container  -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hm, looks like media can only be applied on the whole windows size though :( the element I'm talking about is only part of a bigger div with other elements and the div gets resized, not the window

Comment: You can use @media for any div inside your website just to re-arrange according to different screen sizes.

Comment: ok, I will try that, seems like calling a function on resize really is the best option, thanks :)

Comment: I have EDIT'ed my answer for a complete code by also showing you how @media works.

Comment: thanks a lot for putting so much effort into this! It still ony applies to screen/window size though and not to the size of the div (the div itself is resizable independently of window size, sorry if I didnt make that clear in my post :S) I still don't know how I would get the size of a div with media, all sources where I looked say it only works with screen size

Comment: I added a container div at the width of 870px to keep things compact, but the rest of the other divs have a percentage width, but you can play around with @ media and make your widths as it works for you inside your re-sizable window.  It still serves for neatly placing things according all the outer changing elements.  That's what I love about @media.  Good luck and you are much welcome  :)

Comment: but my window isn't resizable, my div is and the @ media only reacts when the window gets resized - there is no way to make it notice a change of div height to my knowledge - Please correct me if I'm wrong but when the window stays the same how can @ media notice when the user resizes the div? (resize: horizontal in css) I couldnt find a command for that, it said everywhere that it's not possible - and in your example you use "only screen" too which is only for window resize (which never happens in my example, the div is the only thing changing size)

Comment: Do you have some live site where I can see your example?  Or some other way that can make me understand the type of window you are using, but in action?

Answer (score 0):

As you said in a comment that its not about div gets resized or not the window. Then you may be get it solved by applying this -

```
.addMoney{
    display:inline-block;
}

.showMoney{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You will get what you are looking for.

Comment: that's what I have at the moment and then the last element of div B gets pushed to the next line first - I want the inline to apply first to the outer div B though and only then to also break up A and B into the inner divs

Comment: Do you've a live page of what you are codding of?

Comment: and btw, what you have on JSFiddle code is addMoney and showMoney are 'inline', not 'inline-block'.

Comment: I also tried with inline block but none had the effect I wanted - with inline block it's in two lines from the beginning